# Angular - Binding variable on selected value from dropdown list

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I wonder, how do i bind a variable depending on the selected value of a dropdown menu.
[image: My dropdown list]
For now, I have that :

```
this.moleCaracteristique.pourcentDavoirCaracteristique = this.mole.moleCaracteristiques[0].pourcentDavoirCaracteristique;
```

this.moleCaracteristique.pourcentDavoirCaracteristique is always 70.

**JSON**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "password": "passw",
    "nom": "titi",
    "moles": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "commentaire": "bras droit",
            "nomFichier": "fichier",
            "moleCaracteristiques": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "percentToHaveTheCaracteristic": 92,
                    "caracteristique": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "libelle": "milka"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "percentToHaveTheCaracteristic": 70, //This is where the 70 comes from**
                    "caracteristique": {
                        "id": 1,
                        "libelle": "globule"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 marginBottom10" >
<b>Choisissez une caracteristique :</b> 
 <select class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='optionSelected' (ngModelChange)='onOptionsSelected($event)'>
    <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of options' [value]="option">{{option.libelle}}</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="text-center">

<button (click)="complete()"> Soumettre</button>

</div>
<div *ngIf = "optionSelected">
{{ this.moleCaracteristique.percentToHaveTheCaracteristic}}%
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.getCaracteristiques();

  }
  onOptionSelected(event) {
    console.log(event); // option value will be sent as event
  }
  openModal() {
    this.moleCaracteristique = new Object();
    this.moleCaracteristique.percentToHaveTheCaracteristic = this.mole.moleCaracteristiques[0].percentToHaveTheCaracteristic;
    }
  }

  getCaracteristiques(){
    this.caracteristiqueService.getAll().subscribe(caracteristiques => {
      this.options = caracteristiques;
    });
  }
}
```

When i choose "globule", it has to be 70, but when i choose "milka", it should become 92... 
How do i achieve that ?

Thx very much !

**EDIT**

This is the JSON i get from:

```
getCaracteristiques(){
    this.caracteristiqueService.getAll().subscribe(caracteristiques => {
      this.options = caracteristiques;
    });
  }

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "libelle": "globule"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "libelle": "milka"
    }
]
```

Comment: How does your `caracteristiques` value look like in `this.options = caracteristiques;` inside the subscription?

Comment: @amal, I use this to get the "caracteristiques" that I use as values for my dropdown list. The JSON I get from that is in the edit at the end of my question... Have a look !

Comment: And what is the input property value `this.mole`? Is `openModal()` anytime?

Comment: openModal() is use to open a window for the user to choose a "caracteristique". In this.mole, there  is a JSON with all the informations about a mole: "an id, a comment, a file name and a user_id...

Comment: and all the moleCaracteristiques... : here is an exemple for mole1 from user 1 : { "id": 1, "comment": "bras droit", "fileName": "fichier", "moleCaracteristiques": [ { "id": 1, "pourcentDavoirCaracteristique": "70" } ] }  @amal

Comment: It's hard to visualize the flow of events without seeing the full code. In addition, the long variable names are also a bit confusing, sorry. May be if you can show the relevant sections of your code it will be easier to look more into it